# Knockout.js: move checked items to top of list

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using knockout.js (v. 3.2.0) to create a series of checkbox lists on a page.  For any given list I want checked items to move to the top of the list, and move below the checked items when unchecked.

At first I thought I could use a js function to reorder the list and then call the function after ko.applyBindings which is apparently synchronous (calling it before applyBindingds wouldn't work because the DOM isn't complete yet). Nevertheless, it didn't work.  Any idea how to write a function in the view model that will do this?

Here is my markup:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: targetingViewModel.filteredTargetingInstances('assets')">
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:selected"/>
            <span data-bind="text: value"></span>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here is the jQuery function I found in another Stack Overflow answer:

```
addSelectionsToList = function () {
var $list = $(".target-list");
sortItems($list);
function sortItems(list){
    var origOrder = list.children();
    list.on("click", ":checkbox", function() {
        var i,
            checked = document.createDocumentFragment(),
            unchecked = document.createDocumentFragment();
        for (i = 0; i < origOrder.length; i++) {
            if (origOrder[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked) {
                checked.appendChild(origOrder[i]);
            } else {
                unchecked.appendChild(origOrder[i]);
            }
        }
        list.append(checked).append(unchecked);
    });
}
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: you could sort by checked....

Comment: May be you could subscribe to the list or make it a computed property...

Comment: I think sorting by checked is the way to go.  Thanks.

Comment: @dylanmac Take a look at following answer this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out following Code snippet. hope this is will help you.

Steps I have performed

- Created one viewmodel with class Item with subscribe on change of
  isChecked property.
- There is Obsservable array of list items which
  will contain isChecked property.
- Finally on change of value it
  will call the sorting by selecting value on change in any item.

```js
 function SomeViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.chkLists = ko.observableArray([]);

        function Item(isChecked, name) {
            this.isChecked = ko.observable(isChecked);
            this.name = ko.observable(name);

            this.isChecked.subscribe(function (newValue) {
                self.chkLists.sort(function (l) { return l.isChecked() === false });
            })

        }
         self.chkLists = ko.observableArray([
             new Item(false, "Bear"),
             new Item(false, "Hippo"),
             new Item(false, "Lion"),
             new Item(false, "Tiger"),
             new Item ( false, "Zebra" )
        ]);
    }

 $(document).ready(function () {
        var divEle = $("#sortedList")[0];
        ko.applyBindings(SomeViewModel, divEle);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div id="sortedList">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: chkLists">
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $data.isChecked" />
                <span data-bind="text: $data.name"></span>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```